# Best way to trigger a Node-RED flow from python script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, node-red

I'm running Node-RED on a raspberry pi. I want to trigger a flow at the end of a python script I'm running on the same rpi. What's the easiest input node to trigger and what would be an example of the python code to use with it? I'd like to pass a string variable back

Comment: *"Best"* according to what criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking *best* to be *easiest* then the **http-in** node is probably best

And using something like this will work:

```
import urllib2
urllib2.urlopen("http://localhost:1880/start").read()
```

Where the http-in node has been configured to listen on */start*